# How do I regenerate images that are just gray with the width and height?

Tags: magento2

I installed some plugins and after I did, many (not all) of the images look like this.

[image: Broken]

Any idea how to regenerate these images?

And example url is domain.com/pub/media/wysiwyg/banner/id-20-cat-4.jpg

Comment: May I know which extension you have used?

Comment: 1) Magedelight_Authorizecim
2) BBS_OneStepCheckout
3) MaxServ_YoastSeo
4) Amasty_SpecialPromotions
5) QualityUnit_PostAffiliatePro
6) Amasty_Oaction
7) Xtento_XtCore
8) Xtento_TrackingImport
9) Xtento_OrderExport
A) FME_AddCheckoutAttr
B) Eltrino_Region